# XML Schema: restricting an element from another namespace

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I'm writing an XML Schema for a document type that includes tags from other namespaces. (Atom and GML, to be specific: well-known standards.) Requiring a particular tag from another namespace seems easy enough:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" schemaLocation="atom.xsd" />
<!-- and then, within a complex type definition: -->
<xs:element ref="atom:link" />
```

But in several instances, I need to restrict the attributes on this tag. For example, I need to be able to specify the value of `rel` attribute of the `atom:link` tag. That is, I need to assert that a tag in the namespace I'm writing the schema for contain `<atom:link rel="self" href="..." />` and not `<atom:link rel="somethingelse" />`.

I know how to do this with an `<xs:attribute />` tag on a complexType I'm defining myself, but I don't know how to do this on a tag which lives within another namespace. I can edit `atom.xsd` if necessary, but note that in different places in my schema I need to assert different `rel` values, so I can't just add a single `rel` restriction on every occurrence of `atom:link`.

Is this doable? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a problem. To solve this problem XSD 1.1 allows targetNamespace to be specified on local element and attribute declarations (but only when you are refining a type in that namespace). If you don't have access to an XSD 1.1 processor, your only solution is to "hijack" the original namespace - define a schema document whose target namespace is the same as the namespace you are defining a restriction of, and put your restricted types in that namespace. Your element declarations, of course, can still go in your own namespace.